# Getting specific key from Firebase in Framer

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, get, key, framerjs

im really new in coding so my question might be very easy. 
On image below you can see what i have in Firebase.

[Here's what i have in my Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDgz3.png)

In Framer im using [this module](https://github.com/marckrenn/framer-Firebase) and after writing this code:

```
response = (names) ->
    print names

firebase.get("/test/items",response,{orderBy: "$key"})
```

im getting something like this:

> {-L8S1RLTU3P3Lb-PxtsF:{amount:24926, date:"25.3.2018", type:"c"},
>   -L8S1RTNNySP0quUICNt:{amount:23616, date:"25.3.2018", type:"c"}, -L8S1RYPmG8L_EkYV8Vd:{amount:37863, date:"25.3.2018", type:"b"}}

the problem is that i want to get only **amount**. When im trying to change **$key** to **amount** it gives me an error:

```
{error:"Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "amount", for path "/test/items", to the rules"}
```

I have a feeling that solution is very simple but i can't find it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields are not automatically indexed. Since you're trying to filter `items` by a field `amount`, you must define an index on that field. Following the [documentation on defining indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#section-indexing-order-by-child), it should look something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "test": {
      "items": {
        ".indexOn": ["amount"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to get all the items with specific **amount**. For example i need to get all the items where **amount** is 100 ?

Comment: right now i have this code

`firebase.get("/appMoney/health",response,{orderBy: "type", equalTo: "c"})`

and i want it to give me only those items that have **type** equals "c". Is it possible to do?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at the [documentation on limit parameters](https://github.com/marckrenn/framer-Firebase#limit-paramters). Something like this should work: `firebase.get("/test/items",response,{orderBy: "$key", equalTo: 100})` (since your value is numeric, you should not use quotes around it).